# Reset the state of component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to reset the state of the component once the user revisits the page,  Once the user visits page 1 and goes to page 2 and again back to page 1 `<TextInput>` value remains there. I want to clear once the user changes the screen, `ComponentDidMount`, and `ComponentWillUnMount` don't run on the screen change.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TextInput, FlatList, StyleSheet, Text, View,TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Platform } from 'react-native';

export default class RatesScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currency_search: null,

    }
  }
  componentWillUnMount(){
    this.setState({currency_search:null})
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <View>
        <TextInput placeholder="Search" placeholderTextColor="#919191" ref={searchInput => { this.searchInput = searchInput }} onChangeText={currency_search => this.setState({ currency_search: currency_search.toLowerCase() }, this.searchRates)} style={{ padding: 10, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: "#171717", borderRadius: 2, backgroundColor: '#171717', color: "#919191" }} clearButtonMode="always"></TextInput>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: can you provide the code you have written?

Comment: it is `componentWillUnmount()`

Comment: I have tried using componentWillUnmount but it is not running on screen change. I tried writing console log in it but it didn't print.

Comment: look at using `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` - https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Answer (score 2):

You can use `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle hook in page1 to clear its state..

> componentWillUnmount(){this.setState({})}.

Comment: it is `setState`

Comment: I have tried using componentWillUnmount but it is not running on the screen change. I tried writing console log in it but it didn't print.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `react-navigation` you can use navigation lifecycle callbacks,

you can use `willBlur` of the screen to empty your state.

The code should look like:

```
//This code should go in componentDidMount.
const didBlurSubscription = this.props.navigation.addListener(
 'willBlur',
  payload => {
    this.setState({}); //whatever the default state you want to set.
  }
);

// Also, Remove the listener when you are done in willUnmount
didBlurSubscription.remove();
```

You can study more about the navigation lifecycle callback and events [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle).